# Combine and calculate area of geometries that intersect the same polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, overlap, area

I am working with flood data and electoral districts, both are (multi)polygon data. I have different types of flood data: coastal flooding (in blue below) and river flooding (in green below). I have to compute the total surface of each electoral district that is flooded.

I first compute the intersection between each type of flood and electoral districts:

```
inters_c <- st_intersection(ireED_val, coast_val)
inters_r <- st_intersection(ireED_val, river_val)
```

This is shown in the picture below; the light blue area is the part of coastal flooding that affects the specific ED considered.
[Intersection between flood and electoral districts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjW8p.png)

An electoral district can be affected by both coastal and river flooding. The two types of flood can overlap, but not necessarily coincide, as shown in this picture.
[Flood types overlap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByVpF.png)

As a result, I cannot calculate the total surface of electoral districts that is flooded by summing the areas of the intersections of each flood type, since this would lead to double counting in those cases where the two flood types overlap.

What I would have to do is to create polygons that are given by the union of the intersections for each electoral district. Initially I though `st_union(inters_c, inters_r)` would do the trick, but this creates the union of each polygon `x` with *all* polygons `y`, so it is not what I need. It would by great if `st_union` allowed a `by=ED_ID` option, but this doesn't seem to be possible. Any suggestion on how I could do this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Your latter proposed approach would be mistaken because it would not condition on the intersection with `ireED_val`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the second snippet of code I provided. Seems about as direct as possible.

Comment: I tried it, but the output does not include information on the electoral district identifiers, so I cannot use it to attach the generated values to `ireED_val`.

Comment: Post a reproducible working example that replicates your results please. You should be able to iterate over ever pairwise combination. There are plenty of examples of how to do that on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the suggestion by @socialscientist I came up with the following solution.

```
#Create intersection between flood areas and electoral districts
inters_c <- st_intersection(ireED_val, coast)
inters_r <- st_intersection(ireED_val, river)
inters_cr <- st_intersection(inters_c, inters_r)

#Compute flooding areas of intersection
inters_c$Area_flood_c <- st_area(inters_c)
inters_r$Area_flood_r <- st_area(inters_r)
inters_cr$Area_flood_cr <- st_area(inters_cr)

#Convert intersections to data frames
inters_c.df = data.frame(inters_c)
inters_r.df = data.frame(inters_r)
inters_cr.df = data.frame(inters_cr)

##Aggregate areas of all polygons of a certain flood type intersecting an ED
#Coast
flooded_areas_c = aggregate(
  x = inters_c.df$Area_flood_c,
  by = inters_c.df[c("ED_ID")],
  FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE
)
#River
flooded_areas_r = aggregate(
  x = inters_r.df$Area_flood_r,
  by = inters_r.df[c("ED_ID")],
  FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE
)
#Overlap coast-river
flooded_areas_cr = aggregate(
  x = inters_cr.df$Area_flood_cr,
  by = inters_cr.df[c("ED_ID")],
  FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE
  )

#Merge flood areas to ED based on ID
ireED_val <-  merge(ireED_val, flooded_areas_c, by = "ED_ID", all.x= TRUE)
ireED_val <-  merge(ireED_val, flooded_areas_r, by = "ED_ID", all.x= TRUE)
ireED_val <-  merge(ireED_val, flooded_areas_cr, by = "ED_ID", all.x= TRUE)

#Replace NA from merge with 0 area
ireED_val$Area_flood_c[is.na(ireED_val$Area_flood_c)] <- 0
ireED_val$Area_flood_r[is.na(ireED_val$Area_flood_r)] <- 0
ireED_val$Area_flood_cr[is.na(ireED_val$Area_flood_cr)] <- 0

#Compute total flooded area removing double counting
ireED_val$Flooded_area <- ireED_val$Area_flood_c + ireED_val$Area_flood_r - ireED_val$Area_flood_cr
```

The code is not optimized yet. I will update it when I implement the iteration over the many flood combinations (types, scenarios, likelihoods of event) that I have. But, although not elegant, at least it is working for now.

Comment: The many iterations will not be useful to others without a minimal reproducible example. You also could do all of the data wrangling in about a third of the code if you combined your results into a single long-structure data.frame, and it would scale for arbitrary numbers of polygons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).